# Putting a WPF UserControl on the TaskPane of an Excel2007 Addin

Tags: wpf, vsto

I am making a Excel Addin in VS2010.

The following code work fines if I make a winforms usercontrol

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{            
    var testControlView1 = new UserControl1();
    var MyCustomPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(testControlView, "Hello");
}
```

However I would like to make my UserControl1 be a WPF UserControl. Does anybody know how I would achieve similar functionality or an alternate approach?

As far as I can tell the CustomTaskPanes only allows Winforms Controls to be added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this blog](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/create-excel-2007-vsto-add-in-wpf-control.aspx) post that answered it great...

Comment: The link is broken. Can you please update the link.

Answer (score 3):

Answer summary:
1. Add a .net winforms usercontrol
2. Add a SWF.Integration.ElementHost control to the user control.
3. Add a Wpf control to your project seperately (not to the user control).
3. Use the Hosted Content property (hostedcontentName) of the ElementHost control and set it to the wpf control.